# Crawler and "hidden" link

Tags: python, html, css, web-crawler

I'm crawling a web-page like this one http://www.allocine.fr/film/fichefilm-215143/similaire/.

I want to retrieve for each movies it's link. So I did  a function that will do something like:

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(get_HTML_sim_movies(allocine_id), "html.parser")
    allocine_ids_sim = []

    sim_movie_links = soup.find_all("h2")
    for sim_movie_html in sim_movie_links:
        fiche_film = sim_movie_html.find('a').get('href').split("/")[2]
```

It work fine for all the movies since they are all build the same way:

```
<h2 class="meta-title">
    <strong>
        <a class="meta-title-link" href="/film/fichefilm_gen_cfilm=193113.html">Captain America, le soldat de l&#039;hiver</a>
    </strong>
</h2>
```

But the last one is a little bit different, when I inspect the element title with my browser instead of having: `class="meta-title-link"`, I have `class="xXx meta-title-link"`

And when I crawl it or look at the source code the link disappear and is replace by: `data-ac="==L2ZpbG0vZmljaGVmaWxtX2dlbl9jZmlsbT0yMjY2NDQuaHRtbA=="`

```
<h2 class="meta-title">
    <strong>
        <span class="meta-title-link" data-ac="==L2ZpbG0vZmljaGVmaWxtX2dlbl9jZmlsbT0yMjY2NDQuaHRtbA==">Avengers Confidential : La Veuve Noire et Le Punisher</span>
    </strong>
</h2>
```

Do you know how to get the link and why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in base64 format:

```
data-ac="==L2ZpbG0vZmljaGVmaWxtX2dlbl9jZmlsbT0yMjY2NDQuaHRtbA=="
```

strip first two characters `==` then

```
import base64

base64.b64decode("L2ZpbG0vZmljaGVmaWxtX2dlbl9jZmlsbT0yMjY2NDQuaHRtbA==")
```

it will decode it to `/film/fichefilm_gen_cfilm=226644.html`

Comment: And why are they using this kind of things?

Comment: It's their application design, And what I observed here is wherever the custom attribute **data-ac** is there which is holding anchor information in it and on page load javascript parsing this data and preparing <a> tags onfly. you can see that by inspecting in browser. 
- Might be the reason is to confuse crawlers.